# Azure Private Link Scope (AMPLS) Limits

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-monitor

Can anyone please confirm if this limit of Azure Monitor Private Link Scope (AMPLS) is soft or hard: An AMPLS object can connect to 300 Log Analytics workspaces and 1,000 Application Insights components at most. If it is a soft limit, how can I increase it and what is the max we can increase it to?

I have a scenario where I have a hub spoke network with a single dns. This network supports dev, test, prod environments and we think we will cross 1000 app insights limit with single AMPLS.

Comment: What do you mean with a single dns? Can you please elaborate a bit more on Azure private dns/private link design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's listed like this in the docs I would take that as the limit. Thus a hard limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/private-link-design

An AMPLS object can connect to 300 Log Analytics workspaces and 1,000 Application Insights components at most.